# Finding an object with a certain property value in an array of objects in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a class as follows

```
class Car

    properties
        index
        price
        color
    end
end
```

I created an array of these objects and added several cars to the array. All cars have a unique index. Now I want to find the car in this array with the index 5. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one of two ways:

1. Create an array from the indices and then compare against `5` to yield a `logical` array that you can then use to index into your array to grab the ones that meet the criteria.

   ```
   item = obj_array([obj_array.index] == 5)
   ```
2. Use [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to locate an object in an array with a particular property/value pair (note that this only works if you are using a `handle` class and not a value class)

   ```
   item = findobj(obj_array, 'index', 5)
   ```